# checkbox databinding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a problem with System.Window.Form.CheckBox databinding. I have code:

```
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _movementsBindingSource, "Moved", true);
```

It's working, but i want invert checkBox1.Checked. If Moved is true, then checked = false.
Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a common problem and you have two options:

1. Create another field in the `_movementsBindingSource` which will be exact inverse of the 'Moved' field and bind to it.
2. Do the databinding manually and handle the checked changed events yourself.

By default, databinding doe not have an 'inverse bool binding' sort of an option.

Comment: year, thank you Teoman. I have created calculated field in datamodel.